# Visual Studio Reverts Platform Change from x64 to Win32

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, zeromq

I'm building zeromq 4.0.5.  I need a 64-bit static build.  I'm using VS2013.  When I go into the configuration manager and change the platform to x64 the platform for libzmq remains Win32.  If I manually change that one to x64 and close the dialog, it is back at Win32 when I open it again.  Why?  How do I get it to x64?

[image]

Comment: I would guess this is a problem with the project file. Maybe post that here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by editing the project file (.vcxproj).  I went through made an x64 entry for every win32 entry.

For example, I found this entry:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='StaticRelease|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So I added this entry:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='StaticRelease|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
</PropertyGroup>
```

There were probably around a dozen entries that needed to be added.  No changes other than Win32->x64 were made for the entries.